# IronJS: How to parse JSON(send as string parameter) to a method in JavaScript function

Tags: json, ironjs

I am new to IronJS and facing difficulty parsing JSON in JavaScript method.

My C# Code

```
string jsonString = "{\"Name\": \"Ankur\", \"Sex\": \"Male\"}";
var o = new IronJS.Hosting.CSharp.Context();
o.ExecuteFile(@"C:\CustomScript.js");
var handleJson = o.Globals.GetT<FunctionObject>("HandleJson");
var result = handleJson.Call(o.Globals, jsonString).Unbox<string>();
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

JavaScript method in CustomScript.js

```
function HandleJson(jsonStr) {
obj = JSON.parse(jsonStr);
return obj.Name;
}
```

Everytime I do this, I get error message saying **"ReferenceError: JSON is not defined"**

Guess, "JSON.parse" method is native to browser and which isn't available server side.
I can use jQuery method **obj = $.parseJSON(jsonStr);** as well but don't know how to load jQuery file.

Any thoughts on what I am doing wrong or how to fix it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the fix to it.

JSON.parse is an unknown JS method at Server(which is why we were getting the error)... So, we need to add/load **"json2.js"** before CustomScript.js file and then we will be good.

json2.js can be downloaded from following location: https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js

Following is my updated code.

Updated C# Code

```
        string jsonString = "{\"Name\": \"Ankur\", \"Sex\": \"Male\"}";
        var o = new IronJS.Hosting.CSharp.Context();
        o.ExecuteFile(@"C:\json2.js");
        o.ExecuteFile(@"C:\CustomScript.js");
        var handleJson = o.Globals.GetT<FunctionObject>("HandleJson");
        var result = handleJson.Call(o.Globals, jsonString).Unbox<string>();
        Console.WriteLine(result);
```

No changes are required in CustomScript.js

Cheers!